# Is there a name for the relation $\int^b_a f(x)\ dx=\int_a^c f(x)\ dx+\int_c^b f(x)\ dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

The question is contained in its title. French mathematicians would call such a relationship "Chasles' relationship". This comes for the similarity with the formula $\vec{AB}=\vec{AC}+\vec{CB}$ for vectors that is also called "Chasles' relationship".

Is there a similar name in English?

Comment: I have heard this called interval decomposition, but I do not know if that is the official name for this property.

Comment: I think it is the same name which is used : Chasles' relation.

Comment: I would call it additivity, since it generalizes to the *additivity* of the signed measure $E \mapsto \int_E f(x) \, dx$ with integrable $f$ (though this covers only the case $a\leq c\leq b$). But many preliminary analysis textbooks just seem to leave it unnamed.